# Filter contents of SQL output table

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I am new to PHP and SQL.
I have created a html table displaying sql database output.Now i want to create a filter content column which lets user to filter the table contents on basis of values submitted through filter form.
here's the code

```
<div class="filter">
    <label>Stream:</label>
    <select name="stream" form="filtersubmit" required>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="AB">AB</option>
        <option value="BC">BC</option>
        <option value="CD">CD</option>
    </select>
    <label>College:</label>
    <select name="college" form="filtersubmit">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="XY">XY</option>
        <option value="YZ">YZ</option>
    </select>

    <form id="filtersubmit">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="feed">

<?php

$conn4 = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "signup");
$hfeed = "SELECT id,college,stream ,price FROM items";
$resfeed = $conn4->query($hfeed);

echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>College</th><th>Stream</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>";
if ($resfeed->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resfeed->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tbody><tr><td>" . $row["College"] . "</td><td>" . $row["stream"] . "</td><td>" . $row["price"] . "</td></tr></tbody>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No data found!";
}

echo "</table>";
```

i am using form type filter section ,is that the right way ?
what should i use so that when a filter is selected the content updates without reloading the page.
Should i output my sql table using JSon and AJAx or Jquery.
i dont know jquery,so any help with some code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JQuery POST . Please try below code.

```
<div class="filter">
    <label>Stream:</label>
    <select name="stream" id="stream" form="filtersubmit" required onchange="filterAct()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="AB">AB</option>
        <option value="BC">BC</option>
        <option value="CD">CD</option>
    </select>
    <label>College:</label>
    <select name="college" id="college" form="filtersubmit" onchange="filterAct()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="XY">XY</option>
        <option value="YZ">YZ</option>
    </select>

    <form id="filtersubmit">
        <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="filterAct()">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="filterdata"></div>

<script>
    function filterAct(){
        var stream =$('#stream').val();
        var college =$('#college').val();

        $.post('filter.php', { stream: stream, college : college}, 
            function(retData){
                $('#filterdata').html(retData);
            });
    }


</script>


filter.php



<?php

$conn4 = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "signup");

/**** Please add this ****/
$where = "1";
if(isset($_POST)){

  if($_POST['stream'])  {
    $where.=" AND stream ='".$_POST['stream']."'";
  } 

   if($_POST['college'])    {
    $where.=" AND college ='".$_POST['college']."'";
  }

}
/*** End ***/


$hfeed = "SELECT id,college,stream ,price FROM items".  $where;
$resfeed = $conn4->query($hfeed);

$html="<table class='table table-hover'>";
$html.="<thead><tr><th>College</th><th>Stream</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>";
if ($resfeed->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resfeed->fetch_assoc()) {
        $html.="<tbody><tr><td>" . $row["College"] . "</td><td>" . $row["stream"] . "</td><td>" . $row["price"] . "</td></tr></tbody>";
    }
} else {
   $html.= "No data found!";
}

$html.= "</table>";

echo $html;
```

Comment: thanks !!I havent implemented it yet .once i understand the code.  I, couldnt understand the "retdata" Function.And why are we using the filter.php.